# How do i configure my laptop for Hardware Acceleration for the Android Emulator?

Tags: android, kvm-virtualization

When i was installing android studio, there was a message that your system is applicable for some acceleration. 
it provided a link to this page: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-acceleration.html?utm_source=android-studio#vm-linux

I also went to this page : https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KVM/Installation
for KVM installation. I think so that i ran the code specified there well enough.

Now, my doubt is how to use this acceleration. I want to mention that i am a newbie in ubuntu environment.

Please tell, if i need to do anything else or run some commands before launching android studio.

My system info:
intel i5 7th gen
4 gb ram
Nvidia geforce 940mx

kvm ok gives:-

> INFO: /dev/kvm exists KVM acceleration can be used

Comment: Please update your question with output of `kvm-ok` command.

Comment: What makes you think you are not using acceleration ?

Comment: -N0rbert kvm ok gives: > "INFO: /dev/kvm exists KVM acceleration can be used"

now what do i need t do

Comment: just run the emulator. Take care, all the android emulators on Linux are slow, even with KVM / hardware acceleration.

Comment: thanks for the reply. so far my experience in using android studio in ubuntu has been smooth